# Wrong formatting on 404 error page .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, errordocument

I'm new to `.htaccess` files and I have the following problem: I try to redirect to 404 page but if URL contains a directory that doesn't exist, the error page loses its format.

This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Comment: How do you link the stylesheet in your page please? Could you post the `href` property of your `<link>` tag?

Comment: I fail to see how this question is related to `php`, `html`, or stylesheets. Could you explain what you mean by “the error page loses its format?” Your `ErrorDocument` should provide its own formatting; 404 is an error situation that should not depend on anything that might not be available in this situation.

Comment: @Renardo Yep, the only relevant tag for this question is `.htaccess` nothing else.